# Fusion Charts using php

Tags: php, graph, dataset, fusioncharts

[image: This is what I am getting]

I am trying to generate a graph in php using dataset. It's a multi line graph i.e I have 3 operators : GP, BL, ROBI. I'm able to generate the lines for two operators but the third line is not getting generated for a operator.
This is what I have tried :

```
$smarty = new Smarty();

    if($year == "")
    {
        $year="2014";
    }

    $strpaid = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sdate, '%Y-%m') AS tdate,operator,sum(total_revenue) AS TotalRevenue FROM tbl_revenue_opr GROUP BY operator,tdate";

    //$strfree = "SELECT sum(total_revenue) AS TotalRevenue, DATE_FORMAT(sdate, '%Y-%m') AS tdate FROM funstore_mis.tbl_revenue_opr GROUP BY tdate";

    //echo $strpaid; echo $strfree; exit;
    $resultpaid = mysql_query($strpaid) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());

    //$year = "2012";
    $year1 = $year."-01";
    $year2 = $year."-02";
    $year3 = $year."-03";
    $year4 = $year."-04";
    $year5 = $year."-05";
    $year6 = $year."-06";
    $year7 = $year."-07";
    $year8 = $year."-08";
    $year9 = $year."-09";
    $year10 = $year."-10";
    $year11 = $year."-11";
    $year12 = $year."-12";
    $c1 = "0099FF";
    $c2 = "FF8000";
    $c3 = "008000";
    $c4 = "FB8000";

    //$File2 = "downloadsmanth.xml";
    //$Handle2 = fopen($File2, 'w');
    $manthXML ="<graph caption='Total Revenue' xAxisName='Month' yAxisName='Revenue' bgColor='F1f1f1' showLegend='1' decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' showValues='1' pieFillAlpha='70' pieSliceDepth='15' pieRadius='100' baseFontSize='12' rotateNames='1' formatNumberScale='0'>";
    $manthXML .="<categories>";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Jan' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Feb' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Mar' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Apr' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='May' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Jun' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Jul' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Aug' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Sep' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Oct' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Nov' />";
    $manthXML .="<category name='Dec' />";
    $manthXML .="</categories>";

    $opname = "1";
    $opname1 = "1";
    $i=1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultpaid))
    {

        if($opname1 != "1")
        {
            $opname = $row["operator"];
        }
        //echo $opname;
        //echo $opname1;

        if($opname != $opname1)
        {
            $clr = "c".$i;
            $manthXML .="<dataset seriesname='".$opname1."' color='".$$clr."' showValue='1' alpha='100' anchorAlpha='0' lineThickness='2'>";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$janVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$febVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$marVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$aprVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$mayVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$junVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$julVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$augVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$sepVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$octVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$novVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="<set value='".$decVal."' />";
            $manthXML .="</dataset>";

            $janVal=0;
            $febVal=0;
            $marVal=0;
            $aprVal=0;
            $mayVal=0;
            $junVal=0;
            $julVal=0;
            $augVal=0;
            $sepVal=0;
            $octVal=0;
            $novVal=0;
            $decVal=0;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }

        if($row["tdate"] == $year1)
        {
            $janVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year2)
        {
            $febVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year3)
        {
            $marVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year4)
        {
            $aprVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year5)
        {
            $mayVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year6)
        {
            $junVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year7)
        {
            $julVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year8)
        {
            $augVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year9)
        {
            $sepVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year10)
        {
            $octVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year11)
        {
            $novVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }
        if($row["tdate"] == $year12)
        {
            $decVal = $row["TotalRevenue"];
        }

        $opname1 = $row["operator"];

    }

    $totalpaid = $janVal+$febVal+$marVal+$aprVal+$mayVal+$junVal+$julVal+$augVal+$sepVal+$octVal+$novVal+$decVal;
    $totalpaidavg = ($totalpaid/$avg);

    $manthXML .='</graph>';
```

Please tell where I am going wrong ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ROBI dataset is being fetched and dataset is being generated. Try echo "$manthXML" before rendering the chart.